# syntax error in magento module

Tags: php, magento, block

I have created a new page in magento as

http://istockphp.com/magento/adding-custom-page-to-the-customer-account-dashboard/

It is working fine in my local machine,But it returns an error in my live server when i try to load that page

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Istockphp_Customerpage_Block_C' (T_STRING) in 
/home/public_html/app/code/local/Istockphp/Customerpage/Block/Customer.php on line 1
```

Here is my customer.php file contents

```
<?php
class Istockphp_Customerpage_Block_Customer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

Comment: can you share your "Customer.php" file ?

Comment: Post the first few lines of `/Customer.php`

Answer (score 0):

As per the link you are following, the Block file `customer.php` is as follows.

```
<?php

class Istockphp_Customerpage_Block_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard  {

}
```

It is extending the `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard`. But in the above file you are extending the  `Mage_Core_Block_Template`..